# openpyxl - read xlsx in read_mode and preserve cell number formatting

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a large xlsx file (20mb). I am reading this file in `read_only` mode. Is there a way to read the cell values as it appears in Excel, maybe like a "`preserve_cell_number_formatting`" option?

In Excel my value shows as `99%` but openpyxl will read/return it as `0.99990000`. I would rather have the cell value returned as it appears in Excel, as '99%'.

I know I can read the cell formatting (`ws.cell(i, j).number_format`) if I read the file in normal mode but this file is too big to load into memory.

`tabulator-py` for example has an option to read xlsx file while preserving the cell formatting and they use openpyxl so I was curious if this was possible in openpyxl? Here's how `tabulator-py` is preserving the cell's format - https://github.com/frictionlessdata/tabulator-py/commit/e41235b1152c75e013fc53cc42b8989464db3a5c

Comment: read-only mode preserves the formatting but you'd have to implement your own converter from Excel's formatting to Python's.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I wouldn't have to convert the values from floats to percentage myself in python if the values being returned via read_mode were the formatted values, i.e. values as it appears in Excel, not the underlying values.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's read-only mode or not. If the value is 0.99 and you want percentage formatting (convert to a string), that's your job. But you can **always** check the number format.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your time @CharlieClark!